# Cannot access $Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts using pwsh.exe?

Tags: powershell, deno

I want to read the automatic variable `$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts`, using a [Deno](https://deno.land/) script.

I already know how to execute `pwsh.exe` from Deno.

But would like to know how to invoke `pwsh.exe` to get the `$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts` value.

For example, I expect that two commands below yields the same results rather than different results:

```
PS> $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts
C:\Users\Flavio\Documents\PowerShell\profile.ps1
PS> pwsh.exe -noprofile -Command "{$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts}"
C:\Users\Flavio\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1.CurrentUserAllHosts
```

> Note: I'm using Powershell 7.2.5, on Windows 10 and I can guarantee that `pwsh.exe` is the same version for all instances.

Comment: Given that you're running this from within PowerShell, you have to allow the expansion of the referenced property as well. We do this using a sub-expression operator `$()`. So, it would be: `pwsh.exe -noprofile -Command "'$($profile.CurrentUserAllHosts)'"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things to keep in mind here:

1. You're running the command in PowerShell itself, so `$profile` is actually expanded in your parent-session due to the double-quotes in your `-Command` argument.
2. You're passing a string **with** a scriptblock as the `-Command` argument. It's not actually executed - you're just getting the result of `{$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts}.ToString()` which is the content of the scriptblock.

Suggestions:

- Add a call operator to invoke the scriptblock in the string, ex `-Command '& { $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts }'`. If invoking `pwsh` from PowerShell you can also use `pwsh.exe -noprofile -Command { $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts }`.
- Or provide the command as a simple string, ex. `-Command '$profile.CurrentUserAllHosts'`

In both alternatives, remember single quotes OR escaping the dollar-sign with backtick.